# Псевдоэлемент ::before

Tags: html, css, scss

```
.numbers {
        &::before {
            content: url(../../img/shape_32_263.png);
            position: relative;
            right: 30px;
        }
    }
```

**Хочу так**
[image: хочу чтобы получилось так]
[image: но у меня получается так]
**но получается так**

Answer (score 0):

Так или как?

```css
.numbers::before {
    content: 'Допустим Иконка';
    position: absolute;
    left: -50px;
    top: calc(50% - 20px);
    display: block;
    width: 30px;
    height: 40px;
    background: black;
    font-size: 0;
}
.numbers {
  position: relative;
  background: black;
  padding: 12px;
  color: white;
  font-size: 30px;
  margin-left: 50px;
}
```

```html
<div class="numbers">
  (937)444-44-44
</div>
```